# Load multiple images with Javascript from Django backend

Tags: javascript, python, django

I'm working on a d3 based visualization tool that allows users to click paths on images. That works all fine until I tried to let the user change the background image by a simple dropdown.

The problem was that javascript can not load files from the disk since to Cross-Origin permissions. So the solution I picked was to set up a backend. I choose Django.

This is the javascript code which manipulates the image:

```
window.LOADED_FILE = "PUT PATH HERE";
```

I have a working dropdown where the user can pick an image and I get then the path to the file. After this, I tried to load the image like the following.

```
window.SVG.append("image")
        .attr("width", window.WIDTH + "px")
        .attr("height", window.HEIGHT + "px")
        .attr("xlink:href", window.LOADED_FILE);
```

This doesn't work at all and I only get a placeholder image for the 404 Request. So tried to following two things:

1. First of all, this is a solution that I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27932983/django-static-path-in-javascript-file).
   This works fine, but I don't want and I cant hardcode every possible image into an HTML file just to pick the correct variable when the user wants to select another image them later when the user wants. So I need a more dynamic solution.
2. After this, I tried the [following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17893101/reference-static-images-from-javascript-in-django). But when I do `console.log(DJANGO_STATIC_URL)` I get a an empty log. In the settings.py file contains the following static url: `STATIC_URL = '/static/'`.

So what I want is a solution on how I should load images with javascript without hardcoding them in before in an HTML file. I suspect that I have misunderstood something or ignored something obvious.

Comment: Let me get this straight, so you want to be able to load all the images from the 'static' folder in the page, using JavaScript?

Comment: `{{ STATIC_URL }}` is only in the context if you have `django.template.context_processors.static` in your `TEMPLATES` context_processors options.

Comment: @CatalinHoha yes exactly, but I don't want to have in my HTML file all images as variables. There are other parts of the workflow which generates the images and put them in the static folder.

Comment: @dirkgroten I'll see if that helps me thank you.

Comment: @dirkgroten It worked, with the flag I can access my static folder and build the complete path. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{{ STATIC_URL }}` is only in the context if you have `"django.template.context_processors.static"` in your `TEMPLATES` context_processors options in settings.py.